# Add onclick event in an table in php

Tags: javascript, php

I try to add this line to my PHP code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('yourpage.htm','pagename','resizable,height=640,width=360'); return false;">New Page</a>
```

**PHP:**

```
$html_table .= "<td> <a href="#" onClick="window.open('mypage.htm','pagename','resizable,height=640,width=360'); return false;"><button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>test</button></a></td>";
```

But its dont work with `"` inside.

Whats the best way to change my Code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape quotes:

```
<?php

$html_table .= "<td> <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"window.open('mypage.htm','pagename','resizable,height=640,width=360'); return false;\"><button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>test</button></a></td>";
```

Comment: Great:) That works, Thanks!